# Podio: The sample code for the Python-API imports a module that I can't find anywhere

Tags: python, podio

This is the sample code for authentication:

```
from pypodio2 import api
from client_settings import * #doesn't exist

c = api.OAuthClient(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    username,
    password,    
)
print c.Items.get_item(22342)
```

It gives me the error that it can't find the client_settings-module, and I can't find it anywhere either, neither on my computer or online. Since the code seems to be Python 2, I suspect maybe client_settings is a Python 2 relic? If not, where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if client_settings is just a simple custom module created for convenience. It contains definitions of the client_id, client_secret, username, password - and their values. These are program specific and thus this is not a library module or something but simply a python file that contains definitions for them. You could create one(just open a new python file aka module):

```
#This is in module client_settings.py
client_id = "blahbleeblue"
client_secret = "thisIsSuperSecret"
username = "dora"
password = "theexplorer"
```

Then the example code you gave should work (Of course assuming all of the variables we've defined match the format they need to be in)

Comment: I see, that makes sense. I kind of thought I was just supposed to replace the variable-names with their actual value in the code when running but you're probably right. Still pretty new to this. Thanks!